# Do I get anything for finding all the Toads or doing the other collectable tasks?

Tags: paper-mario-the-origami-king

There are hidden Toads and collectables and holes to fill in and there are ? Blocks to hit in each area of the world, and the game lets you know when you have done 100 percent of each thing (found all the Toads, etc) in an area. Do I get anything for accomplishing these tasks? Or is it all just for the glory of having 100 percent completion?

Comment: I've been seeing people say there's a bonus ending cutscene/"true ending" for getting 100%, but I'm hesitant to post that as an answer since I've avoided looking up further detail for fear of spoiling myself...